# How do you find textbox controls by their names from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Please consider the following segment of code:

```
 protected void displayGannt()
        {
            TextBoxT0.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[0]);
            TextBoxT1.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[1]);
            TextBoxT2.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[2]);
            TextBoxT3.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[3]);
            TextBoxT4.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[4]);
            TextBoxT5.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[5]);
            TextBoxT6.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[6]);
```

Is there any conceivable way of putting this segment of code into a for loop with a counter instead of having to write out a million lines of code? Are there any c# macros that could possibly do this job in a for loop of some sort? I certainly cant think of a way. Your answers are appreciated.

Comment: Get the control by name. Look into Reflection.

Comment: Are the names of the controls fixed, or could you make them an array instead?

Comment: The controls are textboxes. I change their colour to indicate a gantt chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 111; i++)
{
    string currentbox = "TextBoxT" + i.ToString();
    TextBox currentTextBox = (TextBox)this.FindControl(currentbox);
    currentTextBox.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[i]);

}
```

111 lines of code now become 5 lines of code and the processor has to work a little harder so you lose a bit of performance, but such is life.

Comment: Soliman, please be aware that the irrelevant flair you have added to your posts has been [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348014/should-you-edit-out-flavour-attitude-from-questions-answers/348074#348074). The General consensus (so far) is that this add nothing to the post and actively detracts from it.. Please refrain from using this in future.

Answer (score 5):

```
var i = 0;
foreach(var txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(t => t.Id))
{
   txt.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Try the above

Comment: This was going to be my answer. +1

Comment: Only problem with this though, is if he has other Textboxes that aren't named 'TextBoxT?' then it will change those background colors too.

Comment: Nice, but what happens if you later decide to add to the page a textbox with ID TextBoxT00 that you don't want to change its backcolor. This type of code can have unexpected results... But a nice solution though :)

Comment: Yes, might have to tweak it a bit if there are other textboxes present

Comment: You should be able to add a `.Where(t => t.Id.StartsWith("TextBoxT"))` clause and it should be good for him.

Comment: You are on the right track but I had to do my own research to get the right answer. Please see my answer below. I am sorry but I will not reward you for this one because this code does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to reference the text boxes in an array (either at the class level or within the method), and enumerate through that array:

```
protected void displayGannt()
{
        var textboxes = new[] {TextBoxT0, TextBoxT1, TextboxT2, TextboxT3, TextboxT4, TextboxT5, TextboxT6};
        for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Length; i++) 
            textboxes[i].BackColor = getColour(time.moments[i]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this would work? Would not the compiler tell you that you have a textbox control with the same name and get confused?

Comment: It's perfectly legal.  `TextBoxT0` is simply a reference to the actual control, not the control itself; you are allowed to create new references to the same control, such as in an array.  (As a simplified example, `var temp=TextBoxT0; temp.BackColor = Color.Red;` will change the background color of `TextBoxT0` since `temp` and `TextBoxT0` refer to the same object in memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.FindControl(String id)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to get the controls you are after (if web).

```
for(inti i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    Control c = parentControl.Find("TextBoxT" + i);
    if(c != null)
    {
       c.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I think you might have missed the 'T' in the control string..`TextBoxT`

Comment: I think this is a nice solution but the only problem is it does not recognise parentControl and we are talking about a textbox not just any control. I am trying to implement your solution in the following way:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 111; i++)
            {
                TextBox c = parentControl.Find("TextBoxT" + i);
                if (c != null)
                {
                    c.BackColor = getColour(time.moments[i]);
                }
            } The only problem I am finding is that it is telling me that ParentControl does not exist in the current context. Any more ideas?

Comment: Too many problems using this method. Does not compile properly.